# Android statusbar set background color to semitransparent color

Tags: java, android

I've managed to set the statusbar to non-transparent colors. Is it also possible to set the statusbar to a semitransparent color?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#c83f51b5</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#c83f51b5</item>
</style>
```

The color shown is still the same as 3f51b5, without the transparency value. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't easy to achieve, but I found in this blog a solution of your problem for KitKat and Lollipop versions.

[Android and the transparent status bar](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx)